# Why do Tenor GIFs result in a Discord poop image in embeds?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, node-fetch

**Code Introduction**

I was making a command where if you type `p!shrug` it sends a random shrug GIF from Tenor. I'm using Tenor API and **`node-fetch`** for my code.

**Problem**

The bot sends an embed as requested but the image in the embed is a *[Discord Poop](https://external-preview.redd.it/9HZBYcvaOEnh4tOp5EqgcCr_vKH7cjFJwkvw-45Dfjs.png?auto=webp&s=ade9b43592942905a45d04dbc5065badb5aa3483)* image

**My Code**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
    name: 'shrug',
    description: 'Shruggy Shruggy',
    async execute(client, message, args){

        const url = `https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=anime_shrug&key=${process.env.tenorkey}&limit=24`

        const res = await fetch(url);
        const result = await res.json();

        const gif = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.results.length);

        const newGIF = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${message.author.username} shrugs~`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setImage(result.results[gif].url)
        .setColor('RANDOM')

        message.channel.send(newGIF)
        .then(console.log(result.results[gif].url))

    }
}
```

**More Info**

The GIF works when I copy the link of GIF from the embed and paste it, it loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

Ok so basically I fixed it with just a small change

- `result.results[gif].url` returns the Tenor GIF link which cannot be used as an image in an embed.

And the change I made was :-

- `result.results[gif].url` to **`result.results[gif].media[0].url`** which returns a media link that can be used in an embed.

I would be thankful for further help, but this did fix my problem.